# how to no losting zip a big jpg to very small size in php?

Tags: php

how to no losting zip a big jpg to very small size in php?

http://img.choies.com/pimages/93665/5.jpg

this img is a big product image (750px * 1000px), but it takes only 47k. the image is very clear.

bellow is some code of my image class, I resize the jpg but get an more large size jpg (120k).

```
<?php 

class jy_image{

    // ......

    //创建图片把柄
    function create_image($img_path){
        $type=$this->get_image_type($img_path);
        $im=null;
        switch($type){
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
            case 'jpe': $im=@imagecreatefromjpeg($img_path);break;
            case 'gif': $im=@imagecreatefromgif($img_path);break;
            case 'png': $im=@imagecreatefrompng($img_path);break;
            default:return false;
        }
        return $im;
    }

    // 缩小图像把柄
    function resize_image($img_path,$length,$size_op){
        $im=$this->create_image($img_path);
        if($im==false){
            return false;
        }
        $width=imagesx($im);
        $height=imagesy($im);

        //如果原图片的尺寸比预计的缩略图的尺寸还小，直接返回原图
        if($width<=$length && $height<=$length){
            return $im;
        }

        //等比缩小图片把柄
        switch($size_op){
            case 'max': // 最大长边尺寸
                if($width>$height){
                    $w=$length;
                    $h=($height/$width)*$w;
                }else if($width<$height){
                    $h=$length;
                    $w=($width/$height)*$h;
                }else{
                    $w=$h=$length;
                }
                break;

            case 'max_width':   // 最大宽度
                $w= ($width>=$length)?$length:$width;
                $h= ($height/$width)*$w;
                break;

            case 'max_height':  // 最大高度
                $h= ($height>=$length)?$length:$height;
                $w= ($width/$height)*$h;
                break;
        }

        $im_new=imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
        imagecopyresampled($im_new,$im,0,0,0,0,$w,$h,$width,$height);
        return $im_new;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: What does `image_create` do? Do you call `imagejpeg` on the return value? Also, have you tried `imagecopyresized`?

Comment: the method added . this is some of my code here. my code is not able to generate so small of jpg. can anyone do it, I need new zip class

Comment: This function for example: http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php have a third argument $quality, try to fine tune it if you use jpeg output. Maybe it helps. Probably there is something similar for other formats.

Comment: What do you mean by "how to no losting zip..."?

Comment: lossless compress an image